# expected 0 arguments, got 1

Tags: mysql, go

I'm getting an error which I can't see any fix on the internet. I am new to go-lang and I can't see any error in my SQL statement. I am executing an update query in go-lang. the code is:

```
sql = "UPDATE tablename SET id1='' WHERE id2=" +fmt.Sprint(v.acctId)
_, err = db.Exec(sql, nil)
```

id1 and id2 are both varchar. I put the SQL statement in a string then execute it. I tried removing one of the ids but it still keeps showing the error. Also what I noticed is that the value of v.acctId isn't always the same for some reason. I don't know why this happens because when I tried the SQL statement on MySQL workspace, it works fine.

Comment: You should not be inserting parameters into your query like that. See the [SQL Go Wiki page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLInterface) on proper usage.

Comment: is it the part with rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age = $1", age)

Comment: `db.Exec("UPDATE tablename SET id1='' WHERE id2=$1", v.acctId)`

Comment: the $1 is not working for me. it's saying Error 1054: Unknown column '$1' in 'where clause'

Comment: ok @halfer, i will next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

db.Exec has the following signature

```
func (db *DB) Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (Result, error)
```

Args is a varargs parameter, meaning that you can put as many data as you would like. However, for each variable you pass to Exec, there should be a "?" in your sql query. The reason you're getting the error is that you're passing it nil, where you should pass it nothing.

Change

```
err = db.Exec(sql, nil)
```

To

```
err = db.Exec(sql)
```

Alternatively you can refactor your query to the following

```
sql = "UPDATE tablename SET id1='' WHERE id2=?"
```

Then run exec like so

```
err = db.Exec(sql, fmt.Sprint(v.acctId))
```

Comment: the first one seems to have fixed the problem. i'll accept it if i'm already sure about it.

Comment: You should never pass arguments by concatenating strings. That is an attack vector for sql injections. Use the ? syntax and pass them as parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the error because you're passing in `nil` as the second argument to Exec while your query has no parameter placeholders (`$1` in postgres, `?` in mysql i believe) specified.

Instead do something like this

```
db.Exec("UPDATE tablename SET id1='' WHERE id2=?", v.acctId)
```

Also, you should almost never construct your queries by concatenating strings as that leads to SQL injection. So please use the param placeholders.

In case you want to execute a query that has no parameters then do what you're doing just do not pass `nil` as the second argument.

```
db.Exec(sql)
```